# Adding elements of nested datatypes

Tags: c++, list, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


class index_table
{
    public:
        index_table();
        void insert(string, int);
        void find();
    private:
        class entry
        {
            public:
                string word;
                vector<int> lineNum;    
        };
        vector<list<entry> > table;

};

index_table::index_table()
{
    table.resize(128);
}


void index_table::insert(string extrWord, int extrLineNum)
{
    int index = extrWord[0];
    list<entry>::iterator itor = table[index].begin();

    itor->word = extrWord;                                  //why doesnt this work???
    itor->lineNum.push_back(extrLineNum);

}
```

I am trying to find out why the above code is not working. I keep getting a seg fault or *** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001e46020 ***

I am creating a "table" that is a vector or lists that is an entry. Once each word and line number is passed to the insert function it needs to be added to the entry class...

Comment: the elements(list) in table is empty isn't it?

Comment: yes, I guess it is... but I am unsure how to fix it I am thinking something like this `entry* insEntry = new entry;
 
 insEntry->word = extrWord;
 insEntry->lineNum.push_back(extrLineNum);` but how do I add insEntry into the vector?

Comment: just use `push_back` function. e.g. `table[index].push_back(..)`

Comment: `entry* insEntry = new entry;                                      insEntry->word = extrWord; insEntry->lineNum.push_back(extrLineNum);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int index = extrWord[0];    
entry insEntry; 
insEntry.word = extrWord;                                     
insEntry.lineNum.push_back(extrLineNum);                               
table[index].push_back(insEntry)
```